# Почему не работает child_process node.js?

Tags: node.js

Имеется node файл

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;


var phantom  = spawn('phantomjs', [ 'snapshot.js', 'http://localhost:3000/#/index/', 'index']);

phantom.on('exit', function(code, signal) {
    if (code !== 0) {
        return cb(new Error('Exit code is not 0: ' + code));
    }

    cb();
});
```

И имеется файл snapshot.js, который запускается через файл выше.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var system = require('system');
var fs = require('fs');
var url = system.args[1];
var name = system.args[2];

page.open(url, function () {

    fs.write('snapshot/'+name+'.html', page.frameContent, 'w');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Оба файла лежат в одном каталоге. если запустить отдельно phantome.js файл, то все работает. Но запуск с помощью дочернего процесса получаю ошибку:

```
events.js:85
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
        ^
Error: spawn prg ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:746:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1053:32)
    at child_process.js:1144:20
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:503:11)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`child_process.spawn(command[, args][, options])` - используется для вызова произвольной команды. `ENOENT` выбрасывается, потому, что команды `phantomjs` у Вас просто нет. Соответственно не находится файла, который нужно вызвать на исполнение (т.е. нужно проверить, что phantomjs установлен).

Если же команда`phantomjs` есть - нужно проверить, что скрипт для него лежит имено по пути `'snapshot.js'`, т.к. в вопросе указан путь `'phantome.js'`.

---

Попробуйте также передать в `spawn` 3м аргументом `{stdio:'inherit'}` (перенаправление вывода дочернего процесса в родительский). И добавьте после вызова spawn

```
phantom.on('error', function(err){
   console.error('parentError:', err);
});
```

Добавление вышеобозначенного кода, при ошибке в вызове `spawn`, явным видом даст знать, что ошибка именно в вызове.

---

**Итого**:

Проблема существует в среде windows, баг с 13 года. Возникает из-за невозможности найти команду phantomjs системой.
Для решения необходимо указать полный путь к .exe файлу phantomjs:

- Если установлен глобально, то (для win8) : `C:/Users/  %USER%  /AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/phantom‌​js.exe`
- Оптимальным, с точки зрения удобства использования видится вариант с локальной установкой phantjmjs в проект и использованием его через `%Project_Root%/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/phantomjs.exe` *(обратите внимание, при множественной установке будет использоваться больше объема жесткого диска)*

Comment: Команда `phantomjs` отлично работает, если запустить её из командной строки. Я проверил, что phantomjs установлен, поскольку запускаю файл `snapshot.js` командой `phantomjs snapshot.js` и он работает.

Скрипт лежит и он работает (в название файла описался)

Comment: Снапшоты страничек складываете рядом с файлом snapshot.js?

Comment: нет, в папку snapshot, которая лежит рядом с файлом snapshot.js

Comment: ну я это и имел ввиду, попробуйте добавить код, который выше дописал. отпишитесь, что получится

Comment: получил сообщение:
`parentError: { [Error: spawn phantomjs ENOENT]
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn phantomjs',
  path: 'phantomjs' }`

Comment: Ммм, тогда, как вариант - пропишите полный путь до phantomjs

Comment: Судя по issue к phantomjs на windown Есть проблема с определением пути до phantomjs (правда issue от 13 года). Предлагают 2 варианта: полный путь, либо добавить путь до phantomjs директории в окружение в PATH

Comment: В файле node.js для spawn прописал полный путь и получил ошибку: 
`parentError: { [Error: spawn C:/Users/ustinov/AppData/Roaming/npm/phantomjs ENOENT]
  code: 'ENOENT',
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn C:/Users/ustinov/AppData/Roaming/npm/phantomjs',
  path: 'C:/Users/ustinov/AppData/Roaming/npm/phantomjs' }`



Прописал путь `C:\Users\ustinov\AppData\Roaming\npm\phantomjs` в переменную PATH, проблема повторилась

Comment: `C:/Users/ustinov/AppData/Roaming/npm/phantomjs` - это же shell скрипт для unix. Попробуйте `C:/Users/ustinov/AppData/Roaming/npm/phantomjs.cmd`

Comment: `C:/Users/ustinov/AppData/Roaming/npm/phantomjs.cmd` выполнение скрипта повисает, и не выводится ничего.

Comment: `C:/Users/ustinov/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/phantomjs.exe` попробуйте. (к сожалению, винды нету, баг, по ходу как раз специфичный для нее) Если не поможет - просто поищите все исполняемые файлы с phantomjs (ну и если все совсем плохо - попробуйте установить не глобально, а локально в проект и запустить исполняемый файл из `./node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/bin/любой_который_выполнится` (вроде как должен быть exe-шник).

Comment: Итого, указав полный путь:
`C:/Users/ustinov/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/phantom‌​js.exe`
или 
`./node_modules/phantomjs/lib/phantom/phantomjs.exe` Я все-таки выполнил файл фантом в качестве дочернего процесса. Огромный респект